# $f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$, $f'_+(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. Can we show $f'_+(x_0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f$ is defined on $(x_0-1,x_0+1)$, $f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$, $f'_+(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. Can we show $f'_+(x_0)=0$?

Here,
$f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$ means $\exists\ \delta>0$ such that $\forall\ x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta), f(x)\geq f(x_0)$. And $f'_+(x)=\lim_{y\to x^+}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ is the right derviative of $f$ at $x$.

If we ask: $f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$, $f'_+(x_0)$ exists. Can we show $f'_+(x_0)=0$? It is of course wrong. Take $f(x)=|x|, x_0=0$ as an example.

But if we assume $f'_+(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$, can we prove $f'_+(x_0)=0$ then?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have edited as requried.

Comment: What about $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe $f$ has no relative minimum! $0$ is not.

Comment: What about $f(x) = \vert x \vert\ $ and $x_0 = 0 $? Surely this is a counter-example. But I am not certain what, "$f'_+(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$" means.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $f'_+(x)=1,x>0; f'_+(x)=-1, x<0$. So $f'_+$ is not continuous at $0$!

Comment: You mean $f'_-(x)=-1, for x<0$?

Comment: @bb_823 no he means $f'_+(x) = -1$ for $x<0$. I think I get it now. Think of $f'_+(x)$ as a function of $x$ . The question is asking if the continuity of this function at $x_0$ implies $f'(x_0)=0.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \geq 0 \\ 1+x & x<0 \end{cases} $$

$f$ has a local minimum at $0$. $f'_+(x)$ exists and equals $1$ at every real $x$, but $f'_+(0) = 1 \neq 0$.